# dynamically get last x months and output as a format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using today's

date, I need to be able to go back *x* months and output in the format of YYYY_MM

At the moment, I am using:

```
select 
right('0000' + cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4)), 4)
+ '_'
+ right('00' + cast(datepart(month, DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2)
```

Which will give me a output of:

> 2015_08

The issue I am having is that if I were to go back 12 months using:

```
select 
right('0000' + cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4)), 4)
+ '_'
+ right('00' + cast(datepart(month, DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2)
```

The output would still be:

> 2015_11 (notice the year is still the same)

**I am using SQL 2008**

## EDIT: Solution

```
DECLARE @table12 AS varchar(50)
SET @table12 = 'SMD_' + replace(convert(varchar(7),DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()),102), '.', '_')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Aaron's answer is much more thorough than my code snippet.

```
DECLARE @MonthsBack INT;
SET @MonthsBack = 11;
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), 
   DATEADD(MONTH,(-1 * @MonthsBack), GETDATE()), 120),'-','_');
```

Learn to use the `DATE` functions such as `DATEADD()` to move through time. Also, `CONVERT` gives you options in how you format *dates* to match the current purpose.  (Which could include formatting for other languages.)

Then, if needed, the predefined formats can be further manipulate as needed.  Though formatting for printing is best done in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that you are not repeating that expression for `dateadd(month, -4`, `dateadd(month, -5`, etc. Here is a much tidier way to develop an aggregate query that covers the past 12 months:

```
DECLARE @start DATE = DATEADD(DAY,1-DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE())
;WITH Last12Months AS
(
  SELECT TOP (12) m = DATEADD(MONTH, -(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY [object_id])-1), @start)
  FROM sys.all_objects
  ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT m.m, COUNT(o.[key])
FROM Last12Months AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OtherTable AS o
  ON o.DateTimeColumn >= m.m
  AND o.DateTimeColumn < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.m)
GROUP BY m.m
ORDER BY m.m;
```

Now, this will output the date as:

```
2014-12-01
```

If you really need `2014_12`, then either (a) format it in the presentation tier (**best practice!**) or (b) do something really inefficient and format it in T-SQL. So the `SELECT` part of the query above becomes:

```
SELECT m = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(7), m, 120), '-', '_'), c
FROM 
(
  SELECT m.m, c = COUNT(o.[key])
  FROM Last12Months AS m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OtherTable AS o
    ON o.DateTimeColumn >= m.m
    AND o.DateTimeColumn < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.m)
  GROUP BY m.m
) AS wasted_cpu_cycles
ORDER BY m;
```

Answer (score 1):

lizzy91 Based on your question all you need to do is repeat the same condition that you apply to get the month to be able to get the corresponding year:

```
select 
right('0000' + cast(datepart(year, DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) as varchar(4)), 4)
+ '_'
+ right('00' + cast(datepart(month, DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2)
```

Comment: that would work but then i would need to add logic to check the month and see if i need to go back a year. i suppose theres some info i left out. but this wouldnt work in my situation. thanks for the help though.

Comment: The "DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())" returns a date that takes into account the change of year. from that date you extract the year or the month or the day... It will always work. Not sure How this wouldn't work in your situation... Please elaborate. RLF's answer is the same concept but more dynamic.

Comment: what i needed was the dynamic ability to do so. my method was focused on getting year and month separately, which is what i didn't want to do. i just wanted to go back x month and spit out a yyyy_mm format